# Drupal 8 Views certain fields is not shown to authenticated users

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-8

I have created a general view to show all the basic page contents. I have selected 'fields' to show and chose title and author name to display. For admin user both fields are populating but for authenticated user only the value for title is showing the field author name is returning as empty. Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for an Anonymous or Authenticated User to see that kind of information, you would have to give them the permission to do so.

This can be done at this path: /admin/people/permissions

- Scroll down the "User Section"
- The permission you want to grant to the user is named "View user information"

That should do it :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That made the charm. I missed that :)

Comment: No problem :) Glad I could help